# Contain current variable name in Exported CSV

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a simple script to scan through a list of workstations, pull their local user info, and export it to a CSV. The code works for doing that, but I am having trouble including any identifier of what workstation the information is related to. At the moment I just get a large list of users and their info.

```
$computerList = gc "C:\Temp\ComputerList.txt"

ForEach ($Computer in $computerList){
Get-LocalUser | Export-Csv C:\temp\passUser.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append }
```

Comment: This would pull the calling system's local user info only, once for each computer in the list. You aren't actually querying the remote computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the property `Computer` to the objects that are output from `Get-LocalUser`.

Also, you are currently running `Get-LocalUser` on your **own** local machine in each iteration.

Try

```
$computerList = Get-Content "C:\Temp\ComputerList.txt"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerList -ScriptBlock {
    Get-LocalUser | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Computer'; Expression = {$env:ComputerName}}, * 
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\passUser.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`Invoke-Command` can take an array of computernames.
It also has a `-Credential` parameter with which you can specify the credentials of a user that has permissions to perform the actions inside the scriptblock